# Send to monitor with mhl-hdmi port

Tags: hdmi

Can I connect a HDMI cable from raspberry 2 to a monitor with MHL-HDMI port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tested, it's ok, at the port entrance it is MHL-HDMI, this was confusing but is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

From a previous discussion at the Raspberry Pi forum it looks unlikely that it supports MHL-HDMI.

Ref.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=106956

Comment: I don't have any business with MHL, the vendor says to me at the phone that can be between two simple HDMI ports. I'll buy the monitor, I can refund it if not.

Comment: I ave no clue what you mean with "business with MHL" and as understand your reply is that you will not use MHL to connect the Raspberry Pi but HDMI?

Comment: yes, I tested, it's ok, at the port entrance it is MHL-HDMI, this was confusing but is not a problem.